# Use dictionary keys as new variable names that include the key name

Tags: list, numpy, dictionary

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

dict = {'Freq_0': 'i', 'Freq_2': 'am', 'Freq_3': 'stuck'}

for k, v in dict.items():
    
    phase_shift_Freq_0 = df['1st col'].tolist()

    imbalance_Freq_0 = df['2nd col'].tolist()
    
    sum_Freq_0 = df['3rd col'].tolist()
```

How can I do this without using exec?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It is not good python to make variable names from strings (even from dict or list).  It can be done, but the code is ugly.

Comment: Please specify what you're attempting to do.